# Why is the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading some machine learning(neural network) related math, and it uses the manifold $M$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.(Every function is a point of $M$)

Why is $M$ a manifold?

BTW, it also says its dimension is infinite because a system of parameters for a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ is the set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$. I think if I know how the atlas is constructed I can deduce this myself.

Comment: The space $M=C([0,1],\Bbb{R})$ of continuous functions is a vector space, and with the norm $\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}:= \sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ it becomes a complete normed vector space (i.e a Banach space). Banach spaces can always be considered as Banach manifolds modelled over themselves... i.e using the identity chart (just as $\Bbb{R}^n$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold). So, the level of details necessary to answer your question really depends on what definition of manifold you're using in the infinite-dimensional setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function is continuous, to determine the function, all you have to do is determine it on some dense subset of $[0,1]$. If this is not clear, let me know and I can add an explanation why. Now $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is such a dense (countable) subset. Take any ordering of these, I’ll denote it as $q_1,q_2,...$.

Then the map that sends $f \mapsto (f(q_1),f(q_2),...) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is injective. I’m not sure what definition of infinite dimensional manifold you use but this will help build the chart. Also you should check that this is map is continuous but it follows from the topology of uniform convergence quite easily. (If you prefer the compact open topology, this coincides with uniform convergence here).